# Save next row value as a new columns Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, lag, partition, lead

I have a table A like

| LDTS | LENGTH |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-03-03 15:41:05.685 | 50 |
| 2022-03-03 15:42:08.203 | NULL |
| 2022-06-08 21:57:07.909 | 45 |
| 2022-06-28 21:58:43.558 | 70 |

I want to display the changes in length side by side in two columns, rather than vertical

So for example I would like a result like this

| LDTS | FROM_LENGTH | TO_LENGTH |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-03 15:42:08.203 | 50 | NULL |
| 2022-06-08 21:57:07.909 | NULL | 45 |
| 2022-06-28 21:58:43.558 | 45 | 70 |

where the timestamp (LDTS) would become the timestamp when the value changed (for example the length changed from 50 to null at time 2022-03-03 15:42:08.203). Is there a way I can achieve this?

I was trying something like:

```
select LDTS, LENGTH AS FROM_LENGTH
             lag(LENGTH) over (partition by LDTS order by LDTS) as TO_LENGTH
      from TABLE_1;
```

Comment: This is right, except you dont want to partition by the timestamp or it will never lag anything (unless its duplicated).

Answer (score 0):

You're very close to the right answer. The problem is that you don't want to partition by anything, because the partition determines the higher-level grouping where the lagging will take place.

Since you don't seem to have a column to partition by, you can `PARTITION BY NULL` if you want.

You also need to add an argument to `LAG` to tell it how many rows to `LAG`. If you add `-1` it will go forwards.

(You can confuse yourself if you `LAG` and then `ORDER BY DESC`, so I prefer to use -1 to lag forwards)

```
SELECT *,
        lag(LENGTH, -1) over (partition by NULL order by LDTS) as Lag_LENGTH_1
from My_First_Table
```

I use this [SQL Generator](https://app.rasgoml.com/sql?transformName=%22lag%22&tableState=%7B%22tables%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22My_First_Table%22%2C%22columns%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22LDTS%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22date%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22LENGTH%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22float%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%2C%22baseTableName%22%3A%22My_First_Table%22%2C%22ddl%22%3A%22%22%7D&formState=%7B%22arguments%22%3A%7B%22columns%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22column_list%22%2C%22cols%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A1%2C%22columnName%22%3A%22LENGTH%22%2C%22displayName%22%3A%22LENGTH%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22float%22%2C%22dwColumnId%22%3A1%7D%5D%7D%2C%22amounts%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22int_list%22%2C%22values%22%3A%5B-1%5D%7D%2C%22partition%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22column_list%22%7D%2C%22order_by%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22column_list%22%2C%22cols%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A0%2C%22columnName%22%3A%22LDTS%22%2C%22displayName%22%3A%22LDTS%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22date%22%2C%22dwColumnId%22%3A0%7D%5D%7D%7D%2C%22transformName%22%3A%22lag%22%7D) to remind me of how to do the syntax for this sort of stuff.